# I have a laptop with my Data Card (Wireless Broadband). I want to share this connection with my Android Mobile

Tags: wireless-networking, android

I have a wireless laptop, a data card wireless broadband and smart phone with Android OS with WIFI.

This is what I want. *I want to use my laptop as a WIFI access point so that I can use Internet in my mobile using the same data card.*

Answer (score 3):

if your OS is XP:

http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/7785.aspx

Vista:

http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/1685.aspx

7:
http://www.tomshardware.com/news/Windows-Laptop-Internet-hotspot-Connectify,8971.html

OSX:

http://maketecheasier.com/create-wifi-hotspot-using-mac-os-x/2009/10/20

otherwise, let us know your OS.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a tutorial about how to share data card internet to mobile and other PCs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XM9SVpjkxgU.